# compare driveletters in use and those are free for mounting image

Tags: batch-file

LS,
At first i'm new to programming.
My study project is to mount an image (e01) to a free driveletter and copy out some registry files and ntuser.dat files.
The image files are on a server \foldername\number\number\name.E01
I have a working (small) script that mounts an image with only single partition. So finding the registerhives wasn't that hard.
Now i want to mount an image with more than one partition so it isn't clear that the partition i need to search for the registry hives is on the first mounted free drive letter.
If there are 3 partitions than there would be 3 driveletters that will be show in explorer.
So i have to determine which drives are already in use before mounting and after mounting which driveletters are added so i can search at those locations. i think compare something and than use the first free driveletter. That driveletter should be added to:

```
osfmount -a -t file -f \\servername\number\number\name.E01 -m #:
```

where the "#" is the driveletter. i don't know if i can alter the command so that it accept that # is a value that is pulled from another line. or something like that. don't know how to explain this.

it has to be in a batch file. so no python or any other scripting language

a co-worker pointed this to me:

```
pattern="foo"
for _dir in *"${pattern}"*; do
    [ -d "${_dir}" ] && dir="${_dir}" && break
done
echo "${dir}"
```

yah, right....

maybe someone can put me in the right direction that i understand.
i will certainly type more code/lines than is necessary but hey, i'm a newbie.

tnx.

Comment: are you working under Windows? This is rather bash but not batch.

Comment: What happens if there are three partitions?  Will the software need three consecutive free drive letters or will it use the ones that are free, and skip an existing drive letter?  Say drive `c d f` are used then will it use `e g h` for a drive with 3 partitions?

Comment: @npocmaka This must be Windows as Linux doesn't use drive letters.

Comment: Can't be windows as that language is not part of windows.

Comment: and \\foldername\ is not a valid path in any os i'm aware of, unless you have a server called foldername...

Comment: sorry i didn't tell the you that it must be in windows with the commandline. So i have to write a batchfile that has to mount an image that has more than one partition. Like foxidrive suggested. If C D and E are in use the next free driveletter would be F. If G and H also are free than other partitions on the mounted image will be mounted in G and H. The code i was pointed to by a co-worker give me no clue. I don't even know if it could be used within a batchfile. The path where the imagefile is located is idd on a server. a UNC path. Hope i give enough info for you to help me. tnx.

Comment: What i do have until now is that de image is mounted at a choosen drive "O:\"  The # at the end of the code-line represents the driveletter. So i could continue with the rest of my script to copy out some files. The image for testing i used was a single partition. But what if it's an image with 2 or more partitions.